# Error on selecting properties for email agent

Tags: java, email

I'm build an agent that will consume a web service to determine what sort of SMTP security and authentication protocol to be used upon firing up an email.

Both authentication and security options are defined in the two Enums bellow:

```
public enum Authentication {
    NONE("None"),
    PLAIN("Plain"),
    MD5("MD5"),
    POP_BEFORE_SMTP("Pop before SMTP"),
    CRAM_MD5("CRAM-MD5"),
    KERBEROS("KERBEROS"),
    NTLM("NTLM");
}

public enum Security {
    NONE("None"),
    PLAIN("Plain"),
    STARTTLS("STARTTLS"),
    SSLTLS("SSL/TLS");
}
```

These falls into respective switch-case structures that will load appropriate properties to the message.

```
protected void init(SmtpConnection smtpConnection) {

    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpConnection.getHost());
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpConnection.getPort());
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

    switch (smtpConnection.getAuthentication()) {
    case NONE:

        break;

    case PLAIN:

        break;
    case MD5:

        break;
    case CRAM_MD5:

        break;
    case KERBEROS:

        break;
    case NTLM:

        break;
    case POP_BEFORE_SMTP:

        break;
    }
    switch (smtpConnection.getSecurity()) {
    case NONE:

        break;
    case PLAIN:

        break;
    case SSLTLS:
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        break;
    case STARTTLS:
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        break;
    }
}


protected void sendEmail(SmtpConnection smtpConnection, String recipients, String subject, String htmlBody, String filename, byte[] attachment) {
    init(smtpConnection); 

    final String user = smtpConnection.getUser();
    final String password = smtpConnection.getPassword();

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, 
            new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    });

    List<String> recipientList = Arrays.asList(recipients.split(","));

    InternetAddress[] iAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipientList.size()];

    for (String recipient : recipientList) {
        try {
            iAddresses[recipientList.indexOf(recipient)] = new InternetAddress(recipient);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object. 
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(smtpConnection.getUser()));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, iAddresses);

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);


        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Now set the actual message
        messageBodyPart.setText(htmlBody);

        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        if (filename != null) {
            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            System.out.println(filename);

            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        }

        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send an email, using this implementation, but I'm landing on this console output error every time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 454 4.7.1 <email@gmail.com>: Relay access denied

at b.c.m.h.agent.utils.Emailer.sendEmail(Emailer.java:182)
at b.c.m.h.agent.utils.Emailer.sendResultlessEmail(Emailer.java:58)
at b.c.m.h.agent.service.ProcessAlerts.execute(ProcessAlerts.java:25)
at b.c.m.h.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:31)
Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 454 4.7.1 <email@gmail.com>: Relay access denied

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at b.c.m.h.a.utils.Emailer.sendEmail(Emailer.java:177)
... 3 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 454 4.7.1 <email@gmail.com>: Relay access denied

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1762)
... 7 more
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the properties, but I fail to see what.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It might be an ISP-specific problem like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/662081/postfix-cant-send-external-mail-relay-access-denied) or an authentication problem like [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187423/relay-access-denied-when-using-smtp-to-external-recipients-postfix-freebsd) - since your authentication switch is empty (or you didn't post the content) I'd guess the latter.

Comment: @Thomas, this smtp server has no authentication and no secured connection - it's a company's test server.